# Play Developer Console not updating apps

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to update an app from google play console

[image]

[image]

I'm updating to 1.01 and 1.02 but the play store is still showing 1.0 with the release notes of 1.02 and the app is not reflecting the changes.

Comment: It takes several hours for the changes to push.

Comment: @greeble31mora More than a day?

Comment: Not generally, no. Sorry, I was thrown off because the 2nd image said 1 Nov/v1.0. I suppose you got the "your changes are now live on the store" notification in your play console?

Comment: yes both (1.01 and 1.02) updates get the notification, i'm having trouble with google maps, when i install the apk in my phone works just fine but the playstore version dont work thats and the "1.0" makes me think is not actually updating the apk.

Comment: Well you're right, the version number on Google Play should've updated. You might want to contact them via Help->Live Chat.

Comment: @greeble31 thank you that’s what I’m gonna to do.